# .net async await, what I am doing wrong

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await

Trying to understand use async await to done some work and something just doesn't work.
have a code:

```
private async Task<string> getStringAsync()
{
    var tsk = await Task.Run<string>(() =>
     {
         Task.Delay(2000);
         return "helloWorld";
     });
    return tsk;
}

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbLog.Text += getStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

the problem is that `getStringAsync().Result` never returns anything.
though according to documentation it should:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `Result`, which blocks until the task completes. You're using that from the UI thread. So the UI thread will be blocked until the task completes.

Now, that task comes from `getStringAsync`, which uses `await (something)`. As the "something" in this case won't have completed by the time it's awaited (because it's a two second delay), you're saying "Call me back when that's finished." But because you're just using `await` (with no `ConfigureAwait(false)`), you're saying "call me back on the UI thread".

So you end up with a deadlock: the UI thread is waiting for the `getStringAsync()` task to complete, but that task can't complete until its callback has been executed *on the UI thread*.

Note that your `tsk` variable isn't a task as one might expect from the name - it's a string, because you're awaiting the `Task<string>`.

The simplest solution is not to use `Result` at all. Instead, make your event handler `async` and use `await` from that too:

```
private async Task<string> GetStringAsync()
{
    var text = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Task.Delay(2000);
        return "helloWorld";
    });
    return text;
}

private async void HandleButton2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbLog.Text += await GetStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: My problem is that this is just an simplified example of what I was trying to do. In real case instead of Button2ClickHandler I have method which suppose to gather results of started earlier tasks. And it can't be marked as async because it is a method in BL layer.
And I was just trying to do multi-threading using async/await approach so ConfigureAwait(false) - works for me. Thanks!

Comment: By the way 'Task.Delay(2000);' also didn't work. apparently the purpose of it is to create separate task which will be execute after delay, but not create a delay in current thread. Replaced with regular 'Thread.Sleep(2000);'

Comment: @user2932688: I'm afraid it's not really possible to help with these very broadly-described issues. I suggest you read a good guide to what async/await does under the covers.